# gulp task running request display log messages too late

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

How would you manage the following task in order to have the messages displaying correctly ? 'Finished' comes before the task is actually done. I guess it's because of the request module. I've tried to wrap the request into a promise but no luck. Any ideas?

```
gulp.task('sign', function() {

  util.log(util.colors.yellow('fetching build number from remote URL:'));
  util.log(util.colors.yellow(JENKINS_URL));

  request(JENKINS_URL, function(err, res, body) {
    var parsed = isJson(body);
    var number = parsed.number;

    return gulp.src(path.join(DIST_DIR, '**'))
      .pipe(replace('<%= B =%>', number))
      .on('end', function() {
        util.log(util.colors.yellow('new build number is: ' + number));
      })
      .pipe(replace('<%= V =%>', VERSION))
      .on('end', function() {
        util.log(util.colors.yellow('app version is: ' + VERSION));
      })
      .pipe(gulp.dest(DIST_DIR))
      .on('finish', function() {
        util.log(util.colors.green('operation ended successfully!'));
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: put the code as a text, not as an image...

Comment: you're right, I don't know why I did that lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is asynchronous (it is making a request). Therefore, you should take a parameter (function) and call it when it is done.

Consider following example:

```
gulp.task('sign', function(done) {

  util.log(util.colors.yellow('fetching build number from remote URL:'));
  util.log(util.colors.yellow(JENKINS_URL));

  request(JENKINS_URL, function(err, res, body) {
    var parsed = isJson(body);
    var number = parsed.number;

    return gulp.src(path.join(DIST_DIR, '**'))
      .pipe(replace('<%= B =%>', number))
      .on('end', function() {
        util.log(util.colors.yellow('new build number is: ' + number));
      })
      .pipe(replace('<%= V =%>', VERSION))
      .on('end', function() {
        util.log(util.colors.yellow('app version is: ' + VERSION));
      })
      .pipe(gulp.dest(DIST_DIR))
      .on('finish', function() {
        util.log(util.colors.green('operation ended successfully!'));
        done(); 
      });
  });
});
```

By doing that, your task will be considered as finished when the `done` function is called.

Comment: Thank you Adam, works very well though calling done() repetitively makes gulp crash with error "task completion callback called too many times". But that's fine, I only need done for that task.

Comment: Why do you call it repetitively? You only need to do this once, and only in asynchronous tasks such this one